# LinkedIn error message "Unable to connect to PERSON. Try again later."

Tags: privacy, linkedin

When connecting to certain people, I get an error message :
"Unable to connect to NAME. Try again later."

I only have had this error with two specific people (colleagues, 2nd connections, both located in Belgium). There seems nothing special about their profile, the "connect" button is displayed, I can click on it like always, get the option to add a note, etc. And with our without note, I always get the same error message.

And this does not happen with other people, I connect daily with others, so it does not seem to be about a connection limit (I only have 2500), or about too many invitations sent (I stay largely within the 100 per week limit).

The only reason I can think of is that I had already send a request previously, and that they reported that they don't know me.

From LinkedIn :

> If you don't know the person who sent you the invitation, you can also
> select the **I don't know this person** option that appears at the bottom
> left of the page after you click **Ignore**. This will prevent that member
> from sending you further invitations to connect. It also gives us
> feedback on whether we may need to restrict the sender's account.

Could someone confirm that this is the reason, or am I missing something ?

It seems the most logical explanation, but it "contradicts" LinkedIn's policy to not show that type of information (like people disconnecting from you, or ignoring your invitations, etc.). They could just let you send the request, and then not deliver it to the other person (as s.he already affirmed not knowing that person).

Answer (score 0):

I just had it too, tried again right away and it worked. The second time my message was shorter. Not sure but perhaps I exceeded the 300 char limit with the first? Then the error message would be just wrong.

Comment: I’ve had the error while not having sent any message.

Comment: Thanks for your message. Well, I had it happening with and without adding a note with the invitation. Re: the char limit, you cannot exceed this anyway, as the input box will just not let you type more.

Comment: I had this 3 times the last two days having sent no message at all.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this message too, but then when checking in [LinkedIn's sent invitations manager](https://www.linkedin.com/mynetwork/invitation-manager/sent/) it turns out that the invitation is showing, together with all the text I'd typed. Similarly, when I refresh the contact's profile, the Connect button has disappeared, and been replaced with a Pending button which when clicked gives the option to withdraw the invitation. So I presume that the invitation was actually sent, and the "Unable to connect" message was issued by mistake.

Perhaps worth checking if that is the case for you?

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. In my case, I checked all that, and the invitation is not showing in the list, and the "connect" button does not become "pending". Since then, I have sent numerous invitations, and the issue only shows up very rarely. Still a mystery to me.